# Does the e-shop version of Link's Awakening have the Color Dungeon?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening

The first time I played Link's Awakening, I played the DX version for Game Boy Color, which had the "[Color Dungeon](http://www.zeldawiki.org/Color_Dungeon)", which awards you with a choice of one of two different stat-boosting tunics if you finish it.

Does the version of Link's Awakening that you can get on the Nintendo e-Shop have this dungeon?

Comment: I believe so, but cant say 100%. AFAIK the 3DS eShop versions of these GB games are the DX (i.e. color) ones.

Comment: You people and your newfangled color... when I was young, we used to play with these big gray-bricks called Gameboy, and Links Awakening was in black and white.... sheesh, kids these days! XD  First game I ever played, nice to know they brought it up a little bit in the generation of handhelds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.nintendolife.com/forums/3dsvc/links_awakening_available_now_on_eshop?start=120#reply-123), yes indeed!

> I can't tell you how great it is to finally get to play the [Color D]ungeon in one my all-time favorite games.

Comment: Awesome. The blue tunic was a lifesaver when I played last, so I was hoping I could get it again! :)